# How to set a semi-transparent color to an Android drawable

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I have some android drawables as icons. I'm trying to change the drawable color to a semi-transparent one.

I've tried to play with PorterDuff.Mode a bit. It works fine with solid colors, but I want the whole drawable to be transparent then change colors. Here is what I have

Drawable file

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
<path
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
    android:pathData="M19.1,12.9a2.8,2.8 0,0 0,0.1 -0.9,2.8 2.8,0 0,0 -0.1,-0.9l2.1,-1.6a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,0.1 -0.6L19.4,5.5a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,-0.6 -0.2l-2.4,1a6.5,6.5 0,0 0,-1.6 -0.9l-0.4,-2.6a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,-0.5 -0.4H10.1a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,-0.5 0.4L9.3,5.4a5.6,5.6 0,0 0,-1.7 0.9l-2.4,-1a0.4,0.4 0,0 0,-0.5 0.2l-2,3.4c-0.1,0.2 0,0.4 0.2,0.6l2,1.6a2.8,2.8 0,0 0,-0.1 0.9,2.8 2.8,0 0,0 0.1,0.9L2.8,14.5a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,-0.1 0.6l1.9,3.4a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,0.6 0.2l2.4,-1a6.5,6.5 0,0 0,1.6 0.9l0.4,2.6a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,0.5 0.4h3.8a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,0.5 -0.4l0.3,-2.6a5.6,5.6 0,0 0,1.7 -0.9l2.4,1a0.4,0.4 0,0 0,0.5 -0.2l2,-3.4c0.1,-0.2 0,-0.4 -0.2,-0.6ZM12,15.6A3.6,3.6 0,1 1,15.6 12,3.6 3.6,0 0,1 12,15.6Z"/>
```

Java

```
icon.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#41F44336"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
```

Tried to change drawable color to white/black/fully transparent combined with different color mods (ADD/OVERLY/SRC/DST) with no hope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the drawables `setAlpha()` method to change the transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setAlpha(). It takes an int from 0 to 255, 0 being fully transparent, and 255 being fully opaque.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android:alpha property of the vector tag.

Comment: I'm aware about setAlpha but I can't use it as the color source is from an external source as a RGBA code

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this after trials and errors is to use white colored icons with `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY`